# Store each function call argument's value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to store the arguments of `abc(10)` and`abc(15)` which is 10 and 15 respectively inside an array `var store = []`.

```
var store = [];
function abc(a){
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        store[i] = a;
    }
    console.log(store)
}
abc(10)
abc(15)
```

Above code's `console.log(store)` gives me this array  `[10, 10]` and `[15, 15]`. I want one  single array `[10, 15]` and so on if I call `abc(20)` 20 array must be added to array and outputs `[10, 15, 20]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the parameter to the array with [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). Your approach changes the values for each call.

```js
function abc(a) {
    store.push(a);
    console.log(store);
}

var store = [];

abc(10);
abc(15);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but where i wanted to implement it did go like that can you tell me an object way to capture the number. I just wanted to capture the arguments. ```var store = {}```

Comment: what is the wanted result with an empty object?

Comment: Actually , my goal is to save the argument value somewhere. Array one didn't help me. May be storing in object would work dear. Thanks for helping btw.

Comment: the array gives a sorted result of the parameter or anything else. an object needs a key. what keys do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you don't need a loop to add values in store. Seconfly you just need to push the values you get in the parameter of abc in store by using store.push(a).

```
var store = [];
function abc(a){
   store.push(a);
}
abc(10)
abc(15)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but where i wanted to implement it did go like that can you tell me an object way to capture the number. I just wanted to capture the arguments. ```var store = {}```

Comment: if you want to store the values in an object inside an array this will do that.
var store = [];
function abc(a){
   store.push({key:a});
}